# Cannot use the Python that I manually installed in my Singularity container. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, ubuntu, singularity-container

I have been creating new Singularity containers with Ubuntu 16.04 every 1-2 months since a couple of days ago and have been using it to run my Python script on our cluster (CentOS 7). However, after making a new Singularity container with a new OS (Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 16.04) and installing the latest Python 3.7 version as follow I cannot run my Python script on our cluster anymore as I get Python import errors.

For your reference, here's how I installed Python 3.7:

```
apt-get -y install python3.7 \
                     python3.7-dev

# Then I install pip and install some packages as follow:

cd /
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.7 get-pip.py
rm get-pip.py
python3.7 -m pip install -U pip
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3.7 -m pip install numpy
```

And here's how I use my Singularity container to run my script:
`singularity exec --nv -B /om:/om /mySingImgUbuntu18.sif python3.7 main.py`

where `main.py` simply does `import numpy`.

Running my script as above gives me Python import errors for the packages that I have installed in the new Python3.7 as if Singularity is using another installation of Python3.7 (which does not exist as 18.04's default Python version is 3.6.9 located in `/usr/bin/python3`). And here's the error I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

When I use either `exec` or `shell` and do `which python3.7` I get the following. Just to make things clear, though obvious, when using `exec` I do `singularity exec --nv -B /om:/om /mySingImgUbuntu18.sif which python3.7` :

> /usr/bin/python3.7

Which is the correct path but my script does not run in `exec` mode and throws Python import errors. If I shell into the container and run either `/usr/bin/python3.7` or `python3.7` and go into interactive mode and then do the import everything works fine. Doing `/usr/bin/python3.7 -c 'import numpy'` also works. So now I am confused on why this is happening when in `exec` mode ... .

Additionally, adding `sys.path` to `main.py` and running my script via `exec` returns the following which shows the correct paths:

> ['/om/user/arsalans/Occluded-object-detector', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bayesian_optimization-0.6.0-py3.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision-0.6.0a0+6c2cda6-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Doing `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages` shows the following which shows that the printed paths are all correct:

[image]

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix this?

Here's some more info for Singularity and the OS version that I'm using:

Singularity version: 3.5.0, installed from source

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

### Update

The issue got resolved magically after building my container the second time!

Comment: Is this a typo, or is it present in your real script `python3 .7-m pip install -U pip`? There's a space between `python3` and `.7`.

Comment: "gives me Python import errors"—what is the exact error, with stacktrace? Those messages aren't for decoration; they contain useful information. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris Sorry that's a typo. By import error I simply mean Python says this package does not exist. I will update my question now

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're upgrading `pip` twice. `-U` and `--upgrade` are the same thing.

Comment: If you output `sys.path` in your Python script does it include the package install locations?

Comment: If you output `sys.prefix` in your Python script does it point to the expected Python interpreter location?

Comment: @gilch doing `python3.7 -m 'import sys'` gives me a similar import error as if `sys` does not exist but if I type `python3.7` and hit Enter and then type `import sys` everything works :/

Comment: @Amir shouldn't that be a `-c`?

Comment: @gilch Sorry my bad. You are right. Doing `python3.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` gives me `['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bayesian_optimization-0.6.0-py3.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision-0.6.0a0+6c2cda6-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']` which is the correct output.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `get-pip.py` instead of simply using [the Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python/python3-pip)? Or `python3.7` for some commands and `python3` for others? If that `python3 -m pip install` command installs to Python 3.6 you won't have the packages in Python 3.7

Comment: @Chris Yes I had to use `pip` that way unfortunately. I don't remember the reason now but I used the Ubuntu package before and things didn't work for me.

Comment: I was suggesting you output `sys.path`/`.prefix` by modifying `main.py` to do that, so that you can launch it in the same environment you're trying to troubleshoot, instead of the shell which might be different.

Comment: @gilch I did that as well. The output is correct surprisingly: `['/om/user/arsalans/Occluded-object-detector', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bayesian_optimization-0.6.0-py3.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision-0.6.0a0+6c2cda6-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`
and `sys.prefix` returns `/usr`

Comment: Is the numpy package actually installed anywhere on that `sys.path`? Trying to figure out if the problem is on the install or on import.

Comment: @gilch Yes, see my updated question for that.